# How to get rid of zero after decimal point?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Calculator {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int firstNum;
    int secondNum;
    int sum;
    int product;
    int difference;
    float division;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter First Number : ");
    firstNum = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter Second Number : ");
    secondNum = scanner.nextInt();

    scanner.close();

    sum = firstNum + secondNum;
    difference = firstNum - secondNum;
    product = firstNum * secondNum;
    division = (float) firstNum / secondNum;
    double firstSquare = Math.pow(firstNum, 2);
    double secondSquare = Math.pow(secondNum, 2);

    System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
    System.out.println("Division = " + division);
    System.out.println("Product = " + product);
    System.out.println("Difference = " + difference);
    System.out
        .println("Square of " + firstNum + " is " + firstSquare + " Square of " + secondNum + " is " + secondSquare);
  }
}
```

[image: Output]

This is a program that takes in two inputs then performs few calculations. I have an issue that I don't want zero after decimal point when I am squaring two inputs. So, how do I get rid of it? Can someone help me with that. Thank you

Comment: `firstNum * firstNum` will return a square without the decimal point.  Otherwise, just cast your original result to `int`.

Comment: Do you just wanna get rid of it or you want to round?

Comment: @JawadElFou rounding works too if it removes the zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't  want decimals either use an int or cast a double to an int. E.g `(int) doubleValue`.  But if you just want to eliminate the .0 from floating point numbers then perhaps this is what you want.

```
for (double d : new double[]{2.3, 2.0,1.222, 4445.2, 442.0}) {
    System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("#.######").format(d));
}
```

prints

```
2.3
2
1.222
4445.2
442
```

For more information on the format syntax, check out [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#DecimalFormat-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with formatting as follows:

```java
System.out.format("Square of %d is %.0f Square of %d is %.0f", 
      firstNum, firstSquare, secondNum, secondSquare);
```

`%d` means an integer without decimal places and `%.0f` means a floating-point number with 0 decimal places as you wanted.

Comment: I believe the OP only wants to get rid of the .0 in 2.0.  Not the 3 in 2.3.  Otherwise they could just cast to an int.

Comment: This is not correct according to OP want.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to string and check for ending

```
public String removePrefix(double number) {
    if(String.valueOf(number).endsWith(".0")) {
        return String.valueOf(number).split(".0")[0];
    }
    return String.valueOf(number);
}
```

Not tested, but I hope it helps. =)

Answer (score -1):

Change the double values firstSquare and secondSquare to ints and cast them to int to change from double that `Math.pow()` returns to int, no need to round since squares of ints will always be int

```
int firstSquare = (int) Math.pow(firstNum, 2);
int secondSquare = (int) Math.pow(secondNum, 2);
```